# Recursively Create an Array from another Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator, spl

I am trying to make a multi-dimensional array build an array path adding the `hr` field so it looks like this:

I just can't figure out how to add the totals, nor create a sub-array so the dot notation in an option too. **My goal is to get something like this**:

```
      [1] => [1][2][1][5][0][6] = 35 (the second child path "1")
      [1] => [1][2][1][5][0][7] = 25
```

**or Something like this:**

```
   array (
      [children.0.children.0.children.0.total] = 20
      [children.0.children.1.children.1.total] = 35
      // etc
   )
```

The complicated part is that it goes in different directions and I want to know what is the highest and lowest total based on the path:

==> [Run Code Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb045ae2105d771efebe50dc848f404318f05b8a) or Copy/Paste

```
// -------------
// The Flattener
// -------------
function doit($myArray) {

    $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArray));
    $result = array();
    foreach ($iter as $leafKey => $leafValue) {
        $keys = array();
        foreach (range(0, $iter->getDepth()) as $depth) {
            $keys[] = $iter->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
        }
        $result[ join('.', $keys) ] = $leafValue;
    }

    return $result;
}

// -------------
// Example Tree
// -------------
$tree = [
    'id' => 1,
    'type' => 'note',
    'data' => [],
    'children' => [
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'type' => 'wait',
            'data' => [
                'hr' => 10,
            ],
            'children' => [
                [
                    'id' => 3,
                    'type' => 'wait',
                    'data' => [
                        'hr' => 10,
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'id' => 4,
                        'type' => 'exit',
                        'data' => [],
                        'children' => []
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 5,
                    'type' => 'note',
                    'data' => [
                        'hr' => 10,
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        [
                            'id' => 6,
                            'type' => 'wait',
                            'data' => [
                                'hr' => 10,
                            ],
                            'children' => []
                        ],
                        [
                            'id' => 7,
                            'type' => 'exit',
                            'data' => [],
                            'children' => []
                        ],

                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];    

$result = doit($tree);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, I found it somewhere googling all day.

```
array_reduce(array_reverse($keys), function($parent_array, $key) {
    return $parent_array ? [$key => $parent_array] : [$key];
}, null);
```